# MATLAB's limiting factors on recursion

Tags: matlab, recursion

Some programming langages, such as Python, have a recursion limits because of the way they are implemented.

Looking at Matlab, recursion does exist and works, but I have been noticing that a very few posts on StackOverflow using it.

What's more, the official Matlab documentation doesn't really mention it, aside from a few posts (note that this list may not be exaustive) :

- [Guidelines for Avoiding Unwanted Recursion in a Chart](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/stateflow/ug/guidelines-for-avoiding-unwanted-recursion-in-a-chart.html?searchHighlight=recursion)
- [MAXDEPTH](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/maxdepth.html?searchHighlight=recursion)
- [MAXLEVEL](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/maxlevel.html?searchHighlight=recursion)

So my question is : Is there a reason **specific to the Matlab implementation** why we shouldn't use recursion on Matlab?

Note that my question isn't oriented on the pros or cons to use recursion, but on the specific limits Matlab could have about recursion.

Comment: Performance is probably the big one, Matlab is slow in recursion. I think it's mainly due to memory management, but I don't know enough about it. Where possible, iteration is faster, and vectorisation is often faster again.

Comment: *Note that my question isn't oriented on the pros or cons to use recursion, but on the specific limits Matlab could have about recursion.* This will definitely save your question from being closed, but it should be in the title. Perhaps something like "MATLAB's limiting factors on recursion"?

Comment: Matlab is not a programming language, although mathworks keep on playing this card. It depends which function you are using recursion with; Is it the Java call? BLAS/LAPACK call? a C library involved? and so on. It cannot have a uniform behavior when all these things are involved.

Comment: @percusse I find your comment really strange - yes, many MATLAB functions are implemented in other languages, but in what way does this stop the MATLAB language from being a language in its own right?

Comment: @Edric It has its own parser but most of the heavy work is done internally by compiled libraries. So in a way it's a frontend. If you call different behaving libraries you get different behaviors which is not a language property.

Comment: @percusse but you can define functions, systems of classes, etc. all within the MATLAB language - that's more than just a front-end to libraries. (Of course, being a front-end to libraries is very important to MATLAB, and that was the original purpose for which Cleve wrote version 1 of MATLAB).

Comment: @Edric Yes you can **define** to put it as nicely as possible. But they are pretty clunky even fake versions of actual programming constructs. Classes in particular are just a joke for my own taste. It fakes an outdated C syntax but anyway. If it works for you it works.

Comment: @percusse : You make an interesting point here. I am looking for a general behavior of MATLAB on recursion but you may be right.

Comment: @percusse Lots of higher-level programming languages, particularly scripting languages, rely on lower-level languages to do the heavy lifting.  MATLAB might be pretty limited as programming languages go, but it is still a programming language.

Comment: @BlackCat Programming language has structures that itself uses for memory management, data handling and so on. Matlab is a high-level parser. It doesn't know anything about the system it is functioning on. Backend is Java and gazillions of gateways. So no it is not. But it's semantics. If you see it that way fine with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB has relatively high function call overhead even compared to other scripting languages.  This makes recursion, which involves repeated function calls, particularly expensive in MATLAB.

Further, due to MATLAB's copy-on-write pass-by-value, any recursive implementation that modifies a passed matrix will be extremely expensive due to having to create and then delete a new matrix each time.

Comment: That's the kind of answer I was looking for, even thought @Edric's one is correct, it does not really answer my question

Comment: Would you advise to replace recursion with iteration (with loops) as much as possible?

Comment: @Hans: I would advise replacing it with vectorized code wherever possible.  Failing that, yes loops are generally better.  Especially with newer MATLAB versions that have JIT compiling the loops can be considerably faster than recursion.

Answer (score 3):

In R2015b and later, the limits of recursion within the MATLAB language are set by the amount of memory. Given a stupid function like so:

```
function out = recur(n)
if n == 1
    out = 0;
else
    out = recur(n - 1);
end
end
```

R2015a errors for `recur(1000)` in the default setting. In R2015b, on my machine, I get this:

```
>> tic, recur(70000); toc
Elapsed time is 0.008121 seconds.
>> tic, recur(80000); toc
Out of memory. The likely cause is an infinite recursion within the program.
Error in recur (line 5)
    out = recur(n - 1);
```